# Add new columns for CSV file

Tags: php, multiple-columns, export-to-csv

I have tree arrays with different lengths, and I want to display each array in a column of my csv file. That's the php script file I am using but no success; I got the data duplicated.
The attempt I tried was to feed empty cells with an empty string so that I can have 3 columns with the same lengths.

```
$categories = get_categories( $args ); 
        $categories_level_1 = array();
        $categories_level_2 = array();
        $categories_level_3 = array();

        foreach ($categories as  $cat ) {
            $cat_level =count( get_ancestors($cat->term_id, 'category') );
            if($cat_level == 0){
                $categories_level_1[] = $cat; 

            }else{
                if($cat_level == 1){
                    $categories_level_2[] = $cat; 

                }elseif($cat_level == 2){
                    $categories_level_3[] = $cat; 

                }
            }
        } 
        fputcsv($file, array(utf8_decode('Catégories level 1')));

        $i=0; 
        foreach ($categories_level_1 as $category) {
            $i++; 
            $categorie_name = array(rw_mb_convert_encoding($category->name));
            fputcsv($file, $categorie_name );
            print_flush("\n liine created");

        } 
        while( $i < count($categories_level_2)){
            $i++;
            fputcsv($file,  array(" "));
            print_flush("\n liine  vide created");
        }


        fclose($file);

        $newCsvData = array();

        foreach ($categories_level_2 as $cat) { 
            if (($handle = fopen($csv_file_path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $data[] = rw_mb_convert_encoding($cat->name);
                    $newCsvData[] = $data;
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }


        } 
        $handle = fopen($csv_file_path, 'w');

        foreach ($newCsvData as $line) {
           fputcsv($handle, $line);
        } 
        fclose($handle);
```

I should get my columns with the  folowwing structure : 
   [image]

But in reality that's the result I got :
 [image]

Comment: Post a sample of the wrong result your are getting

Comment: @gmc I updated my question above

Comment: But use real data in your first image, otherwise it's hard to know how the table should look like